# Using the ASP MVC Default Template

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I am learning MVC and I find the best way to learn is to work on a test project.  However I have a few questions that I cannot find the answer for anywhere.

I would like a website where a user can login to the website and this navigates to a page containing controls (Textboxes, Labels, Buttons etc) where the user can save/retrieve data to/from a database.

Could I use the Default Template for this as this allows a user to login.
Is there any tutorials that cover this concept?

Thanks for your help,

Comment: You could go through the tutorials on http://www.asp.net/mvc

Comment: Check out this http://www.asp.net/identity

Comment: Try posting some of your questions along with your unsuccessful attempts to solve them (with code examples). But as @christiandev said, you should start by reading the tutorials at the asp.net website.

Comment: start here http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/introduction/getting-started

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes and yes, the default template provides the starting blocks for what you need, personally I found these [Chanel9 tutorial videos](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Introduction-to-ASP-NET-MVC/01) helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to search on "database first workflow" - that is what the paradigm you are trying to use if often called.